# Making a Bar Graph from Unsual Data Layout in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying make a bar graph of the data shown below. The x-axis should be "Years" and the y-axis, should be "INCOME," "SPENDING," and "TIPS." In my attempt below, it can be seen that "TIPS" are not following the correct "Year" input.

I created this graph be using the Graph Wizard in Excel.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PivotChart. Go to `Insert` -> `Charts` -> `PivotChart`

[image]